# How to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) in Mac application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, crash

I got one crash report which says app crashed and below is the snapshot

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: isKindOfClass:
```

In iPhone simulators I can try to debug by sending Hardware-> memory warning but in a Mac app how can I debug this ? Even though I enable Zombie and keep it testing I was not able to get the exact location of crash

Comment: Do you have a stack trace that shows what led up to "objc_msgSend()"?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes I have the stack trace, but everything in trace is with `com.apple.Appkit`. I cannot find a single method pointing to my app bundle identifier except `main`

Comment: Do any of those Appkit things use delegates or callbacks that you provided?

Comment: could be memory management issue. Is the crash reproducible? Do you use ARC? Are there CoreFoundation-Types involved?

Answer (score -1):

crash report has meaning in its representation which looks like this

Parent Process:        ??? [1]

Application Specific Information: = no information

Exception Type:        EXC_GUARD

Exception Codes:       0x4000000200000002, 0x00007fff8c4b02a8

Exception Type: EXC_GUARD Exception Codes:

“0x4”.                 => type of guard

“000000200000002”      => the operation which is not allowed

“0x4”                  => indicates that the guard was applied by SQLite